# How does the EF use the callback provided in the LINQ `Where` function to select elements from DB?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq, predicate

How does the EF use the callback provided in the LINQ `Where` function to select elements from DB?

For instance, if I have a query `context.People.Where(p => isOldEnough(p))` does that mean that the EF will query all the people from the DB and then apply the predicate to them and return the remaining result or will the predicate get converted to an actual DB query somehow?

I know that the actual query to DB will happen as soon as the result of the `context.People.Where(p => isOldEnough(p))` will be used somehow (e.g. in an iteration or a cast).

I was not able to find that info on the internet, so I decided to ask it here.

Comment: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/750/deferred-vs-immediate-query-execution-linq#targetText=The%20basic%20difference%20between%20a,Average()%2C%20Max()%20etc. or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution

Comment: No, it will translate your query to proper SQL. Something like `select * from people where isOldEnough(p)`. See [How query works](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/querying/how-query-works).

Comment: @HimBromBeere, will the query be stored in the `context` somewhere?

Comment: You didn't specify which version of EF you are using, but you may find this article helpful as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception Here you can actually see the SQL that the query generates.

Comment: At a high level, `context.People.Where(p => isOldEnough(p))` is an IQueryable, which you can think of an expression tree on top of a context.  At the time you try to iterate it (and not before), it will convert the expression tree into a SQL statement, send that to the database, execute it and get the results.  In your example, it tries to use `isOldEnough` to filter the records, and unless that returns something EF can convert into SQL, you will get an exception saying it couldn't convert it to SQL.

Comment: Of course, that assumes that your context, whatever that actually is, and it's People method returns a deferred IQueryable.  It is also possible that it will return a non-deferred IQueryable/IEnumerable as well, in which case it is no longer LINQ over EF, but LINQ over objects, which is similar, but will never get converted into SQL.  In which case, it would return ALL people from the database and call your isOldEnough for each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF6 the expression:

```
var oldEnoughPeople = context.People.Where(p => isOldEnough(p));
```

where `isOldEnough` is a method in your code base will throw an exception that EF cannot translate `isOldEnough` to SQL.  The simple work-around to this was to slap a `ToList()` in to force EF to evaluate the expression in Linq2Object:

```
var oldEnoughPeople = context.People.ToList().Where(p => isOldEnough(p));
```

The immediate problem with this is that EF will fetch *all* people from the database into memory on your application server before applying the filter. This can be very expensive, especially in a web application where testing with 1 user session doesn't highlight a problem, but in production where hundreds of requests come in, things grind to a halt.

If `isOldEnough()` was just doing logic like comparing if Person.Age >= 18 then moving that out into the Where clause:

```
var oldEnoughPeople = context.People.Where(p => p.Age >= 18);
```

This allows EF to translate the expression to SQL and pass that to the database. The only data returned will be the applicable person records.

Now, when it comes to EF Core, the developers have slapped down one hell of a dangerous landmine (IMHO) in that when EF encounters that original expression that it cannot translate, it will effectively slap the `.ToList()` in automatically rather than throwing the exception. I believe it does raise an alert that it has done this, but otherwise this can be a fairly silent performance pitfall that you should be aware about. However, at least with EF Core, the saving grace is that any query expressions it can translate to SQL will be applied to the SQL first.

For example, given the following expression:

```
var oldEnoughPeopleStartingWithS = context.People.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("s") && isOldEnough(p));
```

EF Core will execute a query to select all people who's name starts with "s" since EF can translate `string.StartsWith` to SQL. Those entities will be materialized and from that it will apply the isOldEnough check in memory. However, this needs to be carefully considered because if that was an OR operation (`p.Name.StartsWith("s") || isOldEnough(p)`) EF would effectively fetch *all* person records before filtering, just like the earlier `.ToList()` example.

When developing with EF, I strongly recommend using a profiler against your database to inspect exactly what SQL statements are being run, and the performance implications of those queries and the amount of data being returned.